# Procesing json files based on the directory name

Tags: python, regex, directory

Within a base directory I have `n` different directories that themselves contain several subdirectories which contain json files. For example:

`$base_bath/foo-2018-11-1/bb/1.jsonl`

`$base_bath/bar-2018-11-2/aa/2.jsonl`

...

Each of these directories will begin with either `foo` or `bar`. I need to process all the `jsonl` files within the child directories differently based on whether the parent directory starts with `foo` or `bar`.

so far i've been able to come up with

```
import os
import re

foo_files = []
bar_files = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path):
  for file in files:
    if re.search(r'.*foo.*jsonl', file):
      foo_files.append(file)
      print(os.path.join(root, file))
    else:
      bar_files.append(file)
```

however, that doesn't return any results.

How can I filter the directory paths such that i can create two collections all files belonging to the `foo` and `bar` directories respectively?

Comment: Why not use `glob.glob`?

Comment: `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path): print(files)` do you get anything? As I just tested, an incorrect directory path does not throw an error, it just gives no results.

Comment: @roganjosh `for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path):  for file in files: if file.endswith('.json'`): print(os.path.join(root, filename))` returns the full path to all of the jsonl files. I need help filtering based on directory name.

Comment: @idclark the answer by Idlehands solves my test case fine

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want the file names? Not the full path?

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path):
    if root == base_path: 
        continue # skip iterating through base_path in case any of those files are a positive match
    else:
        for file in files:
            if 'foo' in root and file.endswith('.jsonl'): # You're now in a foo directory
                foo_files.append(file)
            elif 'bar' in root and file.endswith('.jsonl'): # You're now in a bar directory
                bar_files.append(file)
```

If you actually wanted the full path, do a `os.path.join(root, file)` within the `append()` function.

Edit: In case you're actually looking for the extension `.json`, just update to `.endswith('.jsonl')` on both conditions.

Comment: This works fine in principle on my test case, but the file ending in the question is `.jsonl` and `.endswith('.json')` will fail to find those files.

Comment: I have a feeling that's his typo.  On the topic and the comment he said `.json`.  Either way, it's an easy edit.

Comment: [jsonlines](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [ndjson](http://ndjson.org/) are actual file formats, so `.jsonl` would not surprise me as a file extension

Comment: @roganjosh, thanks, while I wasn't aware of that information (I'm still much of a beginner myself), I read his comment again and see that his code says `.json` but his comment again says jsonl files.  Perhaps you're right, I'll update my answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use os.listdir and os.chdir to navigate into your folders, the code i'm posting is showing the closest solution, using listdir you can iterate through folders without walking into folders that you don't need to explore

```
    In [8]: import os

    In [9]: valids = [e for e in os.listdir() if e.startswith('foo')]

    In [10]: valids
    Out[10]: ['foo-3', 'foo-4', 'foo-2', 'foo-0', 'foo-1']

    In [11]: filepaths = []

    In [12]: for folder in valids:
    ...:     os.chdir(folder)
    ...:     for file in [f for f in os.listdir() if f.endswith('.json')]:
    ...:         filepaths.append(os.sep.join(['.', folder, file]))
    ...:     os.chdir('..')
    ...:

    In [13]: filepaths
    Out[13]:
    ['./foo-3/file-0.json',
    './foo-4/file-1.json',
    './foo-2/file-2.json',
    './foo-0/file-3.json',
    './foo-1/file-4.json']
```